# What does routerProps mean?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

Could someone please explain what routerProps and {...routerProps} means?

```
<Route path='/movies' render={routerProps => <MoviesPage {...routerProps} movies={this.state.movies}/>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks context, for example, what routing library and version are you using?
It could also easily be answered with a quick documentation reading or google search.
Ill assume the library is react-router.
routeProps (not routerProps) is an object holding, unsurprisingly, the route props. check https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Route/route-props

Additionally {...routeProps} creates a new object passing the routeProps properties as properties for the new object. its called spread operator and in this case its applied to an object literal. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

This pattern called [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

> A component with a render prop takes a function that returns a React element and calls it instead of implementing its own render logic.

In your example, `Route`'s prop `render` accepts a function with variable `routerProps` which of type object (because you can spread its entries `{...object}` using [spread syntax](http://%7B...routeProps%7D)) and renders a React element.

```
<Route render={routerProps => <MoviesPage {...routerProps} movies={this.state.movies}/>} />

// Same, props === { path: 'some path' }
<Route render={props => <MoviesPage path={props.path} movies={this.state.movies}/>} />
```